# How do I parse multiple values stored in datum in Plutus

Tags: plutus

So I am storing multiple values in my datum but I don't know how to read them in Plutus code.
Also I am very new to Haskell so explain it in a simple way please.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. It depends on how your datum is stored. Show relevant code. Not all your code, just the relevant part, where your datum is defined and where you are trying to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the free haskell resources:

You may want to learn about record syntax probably, among other things

Haskell and Crypto - Mongolia course by IOHK (Lars and Andres Löh)
https://github.com/iohkedu/haskell-2020

Learn you a Haskell free ebook (really good for quick reference)
Learnyouahaskell.com

Answer (score 0):

you define your `Datum` in your smart contract, so you should show us how your datum is defined in order for us to help you

also if you are using the low-level `BuiltinData` ( the UPLC version of `Data`) keep in mind it is so defined in the [PlutusTx module documentation](https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-tx/html/PlutusTx.html#t:BuiltinData)

```
data Data 
    =
    | Constr Integer [Data]  
    | Map [(Data, Data)]     
    | List [Data]    
    | I Integer  
    | B ByteString
```

in this case it strictly depends by the transaction that has been set to the smart contract that created the UTxO you are spending (which is from where the `Datum` comes).

Also, I strongly suggest you to learn the Haskell syntax before diving into smart contracts, here's a [youtube playlist that helped me](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLckjwRWdD3JToFKE3qzVEI-VhbzVnoJui)